# QEMU - redirect guestOS booting to host machine

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, qemu

I used QEMU to bring CentOS.img (downloaded some where). I find the boot screen of CentOS.img took over the console session of the current terminal and I could see CentOS booting up process and prompts me to the login screen of the guestVM CentOS.  This is really helpful for me as I ran QEMU instance from remote console machine.

Now, I created a new RHEL.img using iso and when I try to boot it; I was not able to see anything in the screen other then some symbol of (Y) :(

```
 $>/usr/libexec/qemu-kvm  -hda ./RHEL.img  -bios bios.bin  -nographic  -net nic,model=e1000,macaddr=00:AD:BE:EF:4F:BD -net tap,script=./qemu-ifup -m 1024 -smp 2
 ...Y
```

on investigation, I find we can do it by redirecting RHEL boot to console using

```
  # virt-edit RHEL_VM /boot/grub/grub.conf
   ...
   title rhel (2.6.38.6-26.rc1.fc15.x86_64)
   root (hd0,0)
   kernel /vmlinuz ro [...] console=ttyS0
   ...
```

but nothing worked out. I am trying to bring the rhel VM session to the same console where I invoked qemu-kvm from remote terminal. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: I don't have GUI enabled on the physical host machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding a serial port and sending output to that. Although you do have to be able to boot it at least once to do these steps...

You might get lucky if you just add a serial port to the qemu command line and then telnet to that; hoping linux detects this and sends output there

> ```
> edit /etc/init/ttyS0.conf and add
>
>   respawn
>   console none
>
>   start on (local-filesystems)
>   stop on [!12345]
>
>   script
>   exec start ttyS0
>   end script
>
> then
>
>     ln -s /etc/init/ttyS0.conf /etc/rc2.d/S99ttyS0.conf
>     ln -s /etc/init/ttyS0.conf /etc/rc0.d/S99ttyS0.conf
>     ln -s /etc/init/ttyS0.conf /etc/rc6.d/S99ttyS0.conf
>
> then do this to enable grub
>
>  Edit /etc/default/grub
>
>  1. Edit the GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT="" line to start the console on /dev/ttyS0
>  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,38400n8"
>
>  2. Add a serial console section
>  # Serial console
>  GRUB_TERMINAL=serial
>  GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=38400 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
>
>  3. Rebuild the grub.cfg file
>  sudo sh
>  grub-mkconfig > /boot/grub/grub.cfg
> ```